# RESTful naming: a POST call that is a GET?

Tags: rest, naming

In our API it should be possible to get all the metadata on some objects (can be over 1000 ids). But how should the endpoint look like?

It is okay to make a `POST api/objects/getmetadata` with the following body?

Body:

```
{
"Objects":[
{ 
"Id":23232,
"Id":3243,
"Id":3243,
...}
]}
```

Comment: POST verb usually refers to some operation that change resource state. Does getting metadata really change resource state? It should be GET. Or you are using POST just to overcome GET limits on query length?

Comment: Nikita yes it's to overcome query length limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide a few parameters which identify the IDs just use `GET` with query-parameters like this:

```
GET /customers?minId=1000&maxId=2000

or

GET /customers?minSalary=500
```

You could also use matrix-parameters if you want hierarchical filtering of only one segment of the URL.

```
GET /api/objects;minId=1000/metadata
```

If this is not possible and you need to pass the full list of maybe 1000 IDs a `POST` is absolutely valid but you should treat it as a request which creates a new resource on the server:

```
POST /api/metadata-search

{ "objects" : ... }
```

The server should return the newly created resource:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /api/metadata-search/4711
```

This way the result has the advantages of a `GET` and can be cached, bookmarked and so on.

Comment: I like the idea of creating a new resource but these id's are random and changes a lot over time.

Comment: You mean a search won't be executed more than once?

Comment: Correct. It will request different Ids each time.

Comment: Then I would not send the `Location?` header and would just return the result in the response. So basically the answer to your question is: Yes, it's OK in this case.